# Is 'something is/are hearts' a valid phrase?

Tags: phrases

I heard someone saying "kids are hearts" recently, and I was wondering if it's a valid english phrase.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.  Please [edit] to add some context to clarify your question.

Comment: It's a valid sentence grammatically, let alone a phrase, but I haven't a clue what it's supposed to mean, unless it goes with "adults are clubs, teenagers are spades and old people are diamonds"